# Phpdolphin increasing the height of profile cover

Tags: html, css

I have recently got this new social networking script and I am not very good with css but Im really good with php. I am trying to make the cover photos height a little bigger as its really thin. I changed the height of the div. the cover photo is set to a background of a div so I changed the height of that div but it is now showing me 2 images the more height I add the more of the second image it shows

[image]

As you may see at the top and bottom the colour of the second image starts to appear and when I increase it alot It goes like this.

[image]

And I have tried setting a no-repeat setting to the div but it then turns on like this

[image]

Anyone who can help me please help

Comment: where is your code?place your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Demo

CSS:

```
#im {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: url("path/to/img");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}


   HTML:

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="im">
        </div>
    </div>
```